# Modern demos of 2D or 3D modeling transforms

Tags: web-browser

My professor is looking for an updated version of 2D or 3D modeling transforms. He used an [outdated version](http://graphics.cs.brown.edu/research/exploratory/freeSoftware/catalogs/repositoryApplets.html) previous years but this one doesn't work anymore. Preferably browser-based if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements, so we can reopen it. Especially missing: what OS should the software run on, what features do you need, how much you'd be willing to spend if it comes to paid solutions…